# How can I get this indentation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I get this indentation?

[image]

I'm using this code

```
\begin{tabular}{rp{14cm}} \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Algoritmo 2} Algoritmo de Guruswami-Sudán para códigos algebraico-geométricos} \\ \midrule
    &\textit{Interpolación:} Calcule un polinomio no cero $Q\in \mathbb{F}_q(X)[Y]$ de la forma
    $$Q=Q_0+Q_1Y+\cdots + Q_{\ell}Y^{\ell}$$\\[-1cm]
    &\hspace{0.4cm} \textit{satisfactorio:}\\[-0.7cm]
    &\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
        \item Para cualquier $j\in\{0,...,\ell \},Q_j\in L(F+(\ell-j)G)$;
        \item  Para cualquier $i\in\{0,...,n \}$ , la función $Q$ se anula en $(P_i, y_i)$ con multiplicidad de al menos $s$.
    \end{enumerate}\\[-0.4cm]
      & \textit{Búsqueda de raíces:} Calcule las raíces $f_1,...,f_m\; (m \leq \ell)$ de $Q(Y )$ que se encuentran en $\mathbb{F}_q(X)$ y genera la lista de palabras clave de la forma $(f_i(P_1),..., f_i(P_n))$ que están a una distancia máxima $t$ de $\pmb{y}$.\\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
```

Comment: I think you should use `algpseudocodex` and `algorithm` packages. Such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656544/238422 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Clara that you should familiarize with some of the algorithm-related packages, especially if you have more than one or two algorithms you need to typeset.

For a quick and not so dirty fix for your typesetting issue, consider implementing a `tabular`-based solution along the lines employed in the code shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,enumitem,ragged2e,amsmath,amssymb,bm}
% Define a column type that performs both hanging indentation
% and line-breaking automatically:
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent % <-- important
\begin{tabular}{@{} P{\textwidth} @{}} % occupy full width of textblock
    \toprule
    \textbf{Algoritmo 2}\quad 
    Algoritmo de Guruswami-Sudán para códigos algebraico-geométricos \\ 
    \midrule
    \textit{Interpolación:} Calcule un polinomio no cero 
    $Q\in \mathbb{F}_q(X)[Y]$ de la forma
    \[
    Q=Q_0+Q_1Y+\cdots + Q_{\ell}Y^{\ell}
    \]
    satisfactorio:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),nosep]
        \item Para cualquier $j\in\{0,\dots ,\ell \}$, 
              $Q_j\in L(F+(\ell-j)G)$;
        \item Para cualquier $i\in\{0,\dots ,n \}$, 
              la función $Q$ se anula en $(P_i, y_i)$ 
              con multiplicidad de al menos $s$.
    \end{enumerate} 
    \textit{Búsqueda de raíces:} Calcule las raíces $f_1,\dots,f_m$ 
    $(m\leq\ell)$  de $Q(Y)$ que se encuentran en $\mathbb{F}_q(X)$ 
    y genera la lista de palabras clave de la forma 
    $(f_i(P_1),\dots , f_i(P_n))$ que están a una distancia 
    máxima $t$ de~$\bm{y}$. \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This affects all tables equally, yes? Is there any way to make it not so?

Comment: @Hopmaths - The `tabular` environment employed in my answer uses a single column of type `P` (with width `\textwidth`). If other `tabular` environments do not use the `P` column type, they won't experience automatic hanging indentation.